# How to change Material-UI TextField/Select error color via createMuiTheme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a custom input style in my application, used in text fields and selects, and provided by a `ThemeProvider`. The theme file looks like this:

```
...
overrides: {
    MuiInput: {
      input: {
        color: '#404040',
        background: 'white',
        fontSize: '14px',
        borderColor: '#c0c0c0',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderWidth: '1.5px',
        borderRadius: '4px',
        paddingLeft: '10px',
        paddingTop: '10px',
        paddingBottom: '10px',
        '&:hover': {
          borderColor: blue[900],
        },
        '&:focus': {
          borderRadius: '4px',
          background: 'white',
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          borderColor: blue[900],
        },
      },
    },
    ...
},
```

I was able to edit the style on focus and hover, but I can't edit the component when the error property is active. My goal is to display a red border in this case.

[image: The error label is showing, but the border color is overridden by gray.]

Do you have any suggestion on how to this with createMuiTheme and overrides? If it's not possible, I'd also be glad if you have a solution using any other styling option.

Answer (score 3):

`TextField` uses [`FormHelperText`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/TextField/TextField.js#L227-L230) to display the helper text below the `TextField`. It is also the error message when the `error` props is set to `true`. The error message color by the default is [`theme.palette.error.main`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/3f9b3d13a28c00c1eacc10e6643546e612ec9eb8/packages/material-ui/src/FormHelperText/FormHelperText.js#L60). So this is how you override the error color:

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    error: {
      main: "#ff00ff", // change the error color to pink
    }
  }
});
```

```js
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <TextField
    label="Outlined"
    variant="outlined"
    error
    helperText="My error message"
  />
</ThemeProvider>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]